# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} not responding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite urls based on subdomain names. But when go to http://test2.domain.com/test/ it goes to http://test1.domain.com/test/ . When I was testing I found that when I removed the first RewriteRule line (of the test1.domain.com part) (RewriteRule ^test/&(.*)$ index.php?menuID=1&$1 [L]) it was working. What is going wrong?

```
###start_test1.domain.com###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test1.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^test/&(.*)$ index.php?menuID=1&$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/ index.php?menuID=1[L]
###end_test1.domain.com###


###start_test2.domain.com###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test2.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^test/&(.*)$ index.php?menuID=2&$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/ index.php?menuID=2[L]
###end_test2.domain.com###
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to vey next `RewriteRule`. Also your regex `^(test2.)?domain.com` is not looking correct.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

###start_test1.domain.com###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/&(.*)$ index.php?menuID=1&$1 [L,B]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/ index.php?menuID=1[L]
###end_test1.domain.com###

###start_test2.domain.com###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/&(.*)$ index.php?menuID=2&$1 [L,B]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/ index.php?menuID=2[L]
###end_test2.domain.com###
```